# Knockout mapping does not produce result

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel, knockout-mapping-plugin

what am I missing? please help.
Here is my code

```
var data= {
"CountyOfPractice":"Bronx",
"Territory":"TERR0102",
 "Specialty":"OralSurgery",
 "Fulltime":true,
"Occurence":false,
"Discounts":"waiver_of_consent,one_time_payment",
"Payment":null,
"Rate":{"Claims made year 1":7668,
"Claims made year 2":14667,
"Claims made year 3":19171,
"Claims made year 4":21181,
"Claims made year 5":22982,
"Mature Claims Made: ":24253}
};

//Create model
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
//bind
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

and here is HTML

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: CountyOfPractice" />
```

and nothing happens the input boxes are empty.
Please advice

Comment: seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cCnry/   are you getting any errors in your console? double check you have included the knockout mapping js file?  posting your full html might help as well

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT.
was using bad link to knockout.mapping
Here is the good one
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.3.5/knockout.mapping.js

and now it works for me as well!!!